# Error 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint on MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

i'm writting a small webapp for the college, but i cant figure out why the MySQL script can't pass. it says "Cannot add foreign key constraint"

Here is the script i'm trying to run.

1) I've checked InnoDB on all tables.
2) If there is any error on FK, but nothing cames out.

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `bdchile` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `bdchile` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `bdchile`.`REGION`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bdchile`.`REGION` (
  `REGION_ID` INT(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
  `REGION_NOMBRE` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`REGION_ID`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `bdchile`.`PROVINCIA`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bdchile`.`PROVINCIA` (
  `PROVINCIA_ID` INT(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
  `PROVINCIA_NOMBRE` VARCHAR(23) NOT NULL ,
  `REGION_REGION_ID` INT(2) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PROVINCIA_ID`) ,
  INDEX `fk_PROVINCIA_REGION_idx` (`REGION_REGION_ID` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_PROVINCIA_REGION`
    FOREIGN KEY (`REGION_REGION_ID` )
    REFERENCES `bdchile`.`REGION` (`REGION_ID` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `bdchile`.`COMUNA`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bdchile`.`COMUNA` (
  `COMUNA_ID` INT(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
  `COMUNA_NOMBRE` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
  `PROVINCIA_PROVINCIA_ID` INT(3) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`COMUNA_ID`) ,
  INDEX `fk_COMUNA_PROVINCIA_idx` (`PROVINCIA_PROVINCIA_ID` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_COMUNA_PROVINCIA`
    FOREIGN KEY (`PROVINCIA_PROVINCIA_ID` )
    REFERENCES `bdchile`.`PROVINCIA` (`PROVINCIA_ID` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `bdchile`.`USUARIO`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bdchile`.`USUARIO` (
  `USUARIO_ID` INT(9) NOT NULL ,
  `USUARIO_CLAVE` VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL ,
  `USUARIO_PRIVILEGIO` INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 3 ,
  `USUARIO_ESTADO` INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`USUARIO_ID`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
PACK_KEYS = 1;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `bdchile`.`SEXO`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bdchile`.`SEXO` (
  `SEXO_ID` INT(1) NOT NULL ,
  `SEXO_NOMBRE` VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SEXO_ID`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `bdchile`.`ESTUDIO`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bdchile`.`ESTUDIO` (
  `ESTUDIO_ID` INT(1) NOT NULL ,
  `ESTUDIO_NIVEL` VARCHAR(51) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ESTUDIO_ID`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `bdchile`.`PERSONA`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bdchile`.`PERSONA` (
  `PERSONA_RUN` INT(10) NOT NULL ,
  `PERSONA_NOMBRES` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `PERSONA_PRIMER_APELLIDO` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
  `PERSONA_SEGUNDO_APELLIDO` VARCHAR(20) NULL ,
  `PERSONA_FECHA_NACIMIENTO` DATE NOT NULL ,
  `PERSONA_DIRECCION` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `COMUNA_COMUNA_ID` INT(5) NOT NULL ,
  `SEXO_SEXO_ID` INT(1) NOT NULL ,
  `ESTUDIO_ESTUDIO_ID` INT(1) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PERSONA_RUN`) ,
  INDEX `fk_PERSONA_COMUNA_idx` (`COMUNA_COMUNA_ID` ASC, `PERSONA_RUN` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_PERSONA_SEXO_idx` (`SEXO_SEXO_ID` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_PERSONA_ESTUDIO_idx` (`ESTUDIO_ESTUDIO_ID` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_PERSONA_COMUNA`
    FOREIGN KEY (`COMUNA_COMUNA_ID` , `PERSONA_RUN` )
    REFERENCES `bdchile`.`COMUNA` (`COMUNA_ID` , `COMUNA_ID` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_PERSONA_SEXO`
    FOREIGN KEY (`SEXO_SEXO_ID` )
    REFERENCES `bdchile`.`SEXO` (`SEXO_ID` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_PERSONA_ESTUDIO`
    FOREIGN KEY (`ESTUDIO_ESTUDIO_ID` )
    REFERENCES `bdchile`.`ESTUDIO` (`ESTUDIO_ID` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;



SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

and the output is just this:

```
**[Err] 1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint**
```

Comment: The error is in PERSONA

Comment: What are you trying? Can one persona belong to more than one comunas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `PERSONA` table you have a composite foreign key `(fk_PERSONA_COMUNA)` which references the same column twice.It doesnt work like that.

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/288e41)